# Apple Numbers - Conditional formatting with equation

Tags: conditional-formatting, iwork-numbers

I want to color a cell green if it’s ≤ A1 × 2.

I can do this with a conditional formatting rule in Google Sheets, but conditional formatting in Numbers seems not to support equations, only referencing cell values as-is.

I don't want to store A1 × 2 in another cell because it would clutter the document, especially in real documents where many cells need several equation results each.

Is there a way to enter equations as conditional formatting tests in Apple Numbers? Or some other way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody stumbles upon this, I ended up using extra cells for equation results + column hiding to eliminate (visible) clutter. Far from ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an IF statement.

```
(IF[cel reference][operator - ≠,=,>,<][limiting number], [specify true result], [specify false result])
```

For example, if there's no value in D3, returns 0, but if there is a value in D3, returns 1.5 (or example, a rate per minute of time that only shows if there's minutes entered)

```
IF(D3=0,0,1.5)
```

Then apply conditional formatting to the result.

Comment: (it needs an "=" in front of the formula, else enter it with the formula tool)

Comment: Could you elaborate on where I’d enter this? If you mean in another cell, this is how I’m doing it now, I was just hoping for something that doesn’t involve unnecessary extra columns.